# Какой тег HTML5 для кода?

Tags: html, html5

Всем привет, какой тег лучше использовать для кода? например я хочу чтобы у меня был на странице <блок>
А вот тут код в виде кода

Нужен именно блок а не текстовое поле

Comment: code и pre но стилизовать не получится так как в codepen, надо использовать textarea и стилизовать уже в нём

Comment: а для вывода html тегов только тег xmp если без textarea

Comment: @MaximLensky, ну и с каких пор textarea можно стилизовать? Наоборот же.

Comment: @MaximLensky, `<xmp>` нет в стандарте. И использовать его нет никаких причин.

Comment: @Qwertiy код html попробуй вывести в html  без `&qt;` и `&ltl;`

Comment: @Qwertiy https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oNXMWzB повторите тоже самое без js

Comment: @Qwertiy так же работает codeMirror и прочие плюшки

Comment: @MaximLensky, запросто: https://jsfiddle.net/z9vtoejk/. А что с codeMirror?

Comment: @Qwertiy  код html попробуй вывести в html без &qt; и &lt;

Comment: @Qwertiy codeMirror так же работает, протухший xmp использует

Comment: @Qwertiy а joomla использует textarea ....я раньше что бы эмулировать codepen делал на html4.1 refresh а выводил его в iframe из за чего не видно как страница перезагружается ...работает в реальном времени без javascript вообще

Comment: @MaximLensky, а зачем мне без `&lt;` и `&gt;`, если правильно с ним? Более того, при использовании нормальных средств оно само получится. А `xmp` - даже если бы в стандарте был, всё равно жирная дыра, потому что пользователь введёт `</xmp><script>...</script>`

Comment: @Qwertiy и что произойдёт ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, ну XSS же.

Comment: @Qwertiy по моему xss быстрее через input словишь через xmp

Comment: @MaximLensky, ??

Answer (score 2):

Блок `pre`, внутрь которого вложен тег `code`, ну а туда уже код.

```
Кстати, SO именно так и форматирует (F12)
```

[image: скриншот разметки]

Answer (score 1):

[Используй спецсимволы](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/tekst/spetssimvoly%20)

```html
<pre>
  &ltdiv id="wrapper"&gt
    &lth1&gtЭто тег h1&lt/h1&gt
    &ltp&gtэто параграф&lt/p&gt
    &ltspan&gtЭто span&lt/span&gt
  &lt/div&gt
</pre>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oNXMWzB

Comment: просто ссылка на codepen ...поглянь

Comment: суть ссылки в том что в html всего два тега которые отображают html - `xmp` и `textarea`

Comment: я знаю что устарел - но единственный в своём роде